# vps ubuntu python could not locate runnable browser

Tags: python, ubuntu, browser, server, python-webbrowser

i trying to run google Oauth with django project on vps ubuntu server

the google flow file use python module webbrowser.py ,

when run the app get error "could not locate runnable browser"

google flow code is

```py
import webbrowser 
webbrowser.get(None).open(auth_url, new=1, autoraise=True)
```

any one can help in this

when remove webbrowser.get(None)
and use only webbrowser.open(auth_url, new=1, autoraise=True)
i receive bad gateway error

Comment: The error message is pretty clear—there's no browser application installed on your VPS. I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do—why are you using `webbrowser.open` in a Django server?

Comment: i already have installed   0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/chromium-browser       40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode

Comment: i didn't use webbrowser.open it is build in function in google auth library as it have callback function in it to get token

Comment: no browser application installed on your VPS.  what is you suggestion to install